# after dismissing the view the collection view miss places the cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a collection view where when you press the cell it takes you to another view to see a bigger picture of the cell. But when you dismiss the view the cells get miss placed. How can I fix this? Please help and thank you!

This images will help understand me
http://imgur.com/FHDqfbI&d5EeBCB&BINMXV3
http://imgur.com/FHDqfbI&d5EeBCB&BINMXV3#2

Comment: kindly share your piece of  code to understand your problem. as in your link 2 images are same is it your problem.

Comment: Is your problem that the order of the thumbnail images changes after dismissing the larger view of the image? (also, like abrar ul haq said, it seems that the two images you've linked to are the same...)